# Insert page number in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I created a document in LibreOffice Writer. I tried to add the page number in the footer by clicking on **Insert** -> **Footer** -> **Default Style**. Then, I clicked **Insert** -> **Fields** -> **Page Number**, but the page number is not displayed. It only displays `Page numbers` (literally) in the footer of all pages. Can any one can help, please?

Answer (score 3):

You have `Show Fields` turned on. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> or click on **View** > **Field Names**